# How to prevent camera zooming with mouse wheel?

Tags: dota-2, mouse

My mouse is incredibly busted and my scroll wheel fires off 'scroll' events randomly. It's really bad for games like Dota 2.

How can I prevent the camera from zooming with the mouse wheel? I'd prefer to even disable zooming entirely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open your console and use this command `dota_camera_disable_zoom "1"`.

This will disable the zoom entirely.

To open the console you need to rightclick your DotA2 in steam and go to properties-> set launch options. There you need to add **-console** and start DotA2.

If this resets every time you start DotA2:

Open your DotA 2 Folder (...\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\cfg) and create a new file called **autoexec.cfg**. Insert the above command into this file. This will automatically apply above command each time you start DotA2

Comment: Much appreciated!